# Auto Replace URL with its title Google Docs

Tags: url, replace, google-docs, title

I add a lot of links to the document (Google Docs) every day. Then I click "Replace URL with its title" for each link. It is very uncomfortable.

Is it possible to automate this process using a script or something else? Please help me

Comment: You find it useful? I came here searching for how to disable that annoying feature

Comment: Yeah, I find it useful as well. It'd be great if Google could add a shortcut here, making this thing a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes it is possible!

What you can do in this situation is to gather all the links you have in an array and then use string manipulation (such as regEx for example) in order to extract the title from the link.

For this task you can benefit from Apps Script - Apps Script is a powerful development platform which can be used to build web apps and automate tasks. What makes it special is the fact that it is easy to use and to create applications that integrate with G Suite.

#### Reference

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script);
- [Text Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text);
- [Document Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document);
- [Document Class Apps Script - replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement).